# Laptop battery fake discharge after hibernation

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, battery-life

Recently I've noticed that every time I'm hibernating the laptop for a longer time (no more than for the night), when it comes back up, it starts at 0% charge and has trouble doing so (tries to shutdown mid-wakening due to low charge). However, the battery is not "dead" -- as per `powercfg /batteryreport`, it still has ~70% of it's original capacity (~44Wh remaining), and it charges very quickly from the initial 0% after resuming from hibernation to 100% (in less than 30 minutes). Further, the charge also holds well, for at least 1 hour, which corresponds with ~70% capacity.

What other tools/ways could be used to diagnose this problem further without sending the laptop to RMA? Is there any chance that this behaviour is due to software (windows) errors?

Excerpt from the battery report, generated by `powercfg` call:

```
Recent usage:
START TIME  STATE   SOURCE          CAPACITY REMAINING
<...>
13:47:55    Active  AC              29 %        235 mWh
13:55:37    Active  Battery         5619 %   45,792 mWh
```

For some reason the full capacity is in thousands of %. Meanwhile,

```
FULL CHARGE CAPACITY    45,792 mWh
```

It feels like for some reason just after the hibernation the battery reports incorrect capacity/remaining, but is able to correct within 10 minutes.

Apologies if this isn't the correct place for this question.

Comment: "Is there any chance that this behavior is due to software (windows) errors?" - No; It sounds like you have a bad battery.  It should NOT be possible to charge your battery that quickly.

Comment: @Ramhound it feels like it's a reporting issue, incorrect values that are understood as 0%. As if it is actually charged at say 90% but reporting (or reading?) a 0%, hence the fast charge. I'm editing an excerpt from the batteryreport into the question text, might explain something?

Comment: Try updating BIOS and the Power driver.  Then reset the battery. Charge to full, unplug and use to low battery shutdown, plug in, charge to full and restart.

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: @Moab used since 2018, but rarely unplugged, almost never with sleep, only hibernation.

Comment: After reaching 100% all seems normal, discharged 10Wh after 30min of use, with makes sense for a 45W TDP laptop. Issues are observed only after reviving from hibernation, in the report I'm noticing that 1 hour long hibernation is enough, after which it reads <100mWh incorrectly for a short time.

Comment: @John Thanks, resetting the battery seems to have fixed at least some of the issues, percentages seem correct and one hibernation was successful. Will need to monitor whether this persists

Comment: I thought that the reset would help so I will post that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Recently I've noticed that every time I'm hibernating the laptop for a
> longer time (no more than for the night), when it comes back up, it
> starts at 0% charge and has trouble doing so (tries to shutdown
> mid-wakening due to low charge). However, the battery is not "dead"

For any battery issue, try updating BIOS and the Power driver.

Then in this case,  reset the battery:

Charge to full.

Unplug and use to low battery shutdown.

Plug in, charge to full and restart the computer.

Reset very often fixes battery issues.

Comment: I read somewhere that it is advised to discharge while in the BIOS menu (so that the windows power profiles wouldn't initiate early sleep). Just curious in your opinion, can this help (or hurt) the reset, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I do not think it matters. I use the Lenovo Battery Reset app and that resets my battery in user mode. You can also discharge it in BIOS for the first step if you wish. I prefer the battery reset app.